# Does Auth0 still be used in azure app services (not mobile service)?

Tags: .net, azure, auth0

Sorry for this rookie question.

Does Auth0 still be used in azure app services?

Upon checking the azure app service -> Settings -> Authentication, we can now set the authentication providers in that section.

Answer (score 1):

@JunM,
You can set the Authentication setting on Azure Portal for Auth0.
I recommend you can refer to this document:

azure-active-directory-native
https://auth0.com/docs/connections/enterprise/azure-active-directory-native

Web App:

https://auth0.com/docs/connections/enterprise/azure-active-directory

Hope this helps